# How to make repeating different calculation in C# array

Tags: c#

I'd like to get numbers from user text box. There is no limit on the value. For each numbers' characters, I will first multiply by 2, 4 and 6 repeatedly and then add it together.

For example, if user input '12', then 1*2 + 2*4 = 10. if the user input '1111' the answer will be calculated like this: 1*2 + 1*4 + 1*6 + 1*2 = 12. First I've set the number in an array, but then I'm stuck on how to make it multiply different value (2, 4, and 6) every time each no is called in for loop.

Is it possible to achieve this in C#? Are there any examples that I can learn on this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you have loop *OCD*, here is a *Linq* solution

```
var result = input.Select((c, i) => array[i % array.Length] * (c - '0')).Sum();
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LDvmu)

The premise is

1. `input` is your string
2. `array` is your numbers
3. `Select` each `char` and index in the string `(c,i)`
4. Get the remainder after division `i % array.Length` for each element `i % length` will cycle through your array
5. Get the `int` value from the `char`, `(c - '0')` (think *ascii table*)
6. `*` them together
7. `Sum` the results

---

**Additional Resources**

[Select(IEnumerable, Func)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating
>   the element's index.

[Remainder operator %](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-)

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its
>   left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.

**Update**

> However, i'm wondering what if the input is also an array (eg. {11,12}
>   in this case they will be calculated like this: 11*2 + 12*4 = 70)

```
var input = "34 5 234 54";

var result = input.Split(' ')
                  .Select((c, i) => array[i % array.Length] * int.Parse(x))
                  .Sum();
```

Comment: thanks. this works like a charm. However, i'm wondering what if the input is also an array (eg. {11,12} in this case they will be calculated like this: 11*2 + 12*4 = 70). is doesn't seem possible to use this method as it will calculate based on every char in the numbers string.

Comment: @fahmijaafar if input `int[]` replace `(c - '0')` with c i.e `input.Select((c, i) => array[i % array.Length] * c)`

Comment: @fahmijaafar also `input = "34 5 234 54"` then `input.Split(' ').input.Select((c, i) => array[i % array.Length] * int.Parse(c));`

Answer (score 3):

```cs
//int[] numDigitsArray // 1, 2 ,3 ,4

int[] twoFourSixArray = {2, 4, 6};
int current = 0;
int res = 0;
while (current < numDigitsArray.Length)  
{
    res += twoFourSixArray[current % twoFourSixArray.Length] * numDigistsArray[current];
    current++;
}
```